# OpenLayers Style Text incorrectly aligned and moving on map resize

Tags: openlayers, markers, mapping

I have an OpenLayers map which I want to display SVG markers on with some text. I have got it to display the marker and it looks fine but when the map is resized the alignment of the text moves by a few pixels. See images below.

This is the marker style I have used:

```
    var markerStyle = new Style({
      image: new Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        opacity: 0.9,
        scale: 1,
        color: '#253679',
        src: 'assets/images/map-marker.svg'
      })),
      text: new Text({
        offsetY: -5,
        text: "AA",
        scale: 1.2,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "#fff"
        })
      })
    });
```

When the marker is first placed it looks like this:

[image]

If I resize the window as you can see the text visibly moves as I resize and is incorrectly aligned:

[image]

It sounds like a small problem but it is making my mapping application look unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the OpenLayers Text style to work correctly so I solved this by adding the text directly to the SVG marker:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 87.302 142.86" version="1.1" width="38px" height="38px" >
  <g>
    <path style="color:#000000;fill:#253679" d="m87.302 43.651c0 24.108-23.511 67.46-43.651 99.206-17.163-32.74-43.651-75.102-43.651-99.209 5.2381e-8 -24.108 19.543-43.651 43.651-43.651 24.107 8.009e-8 43.651 19.543 43.651 43.651z" />
  </g>
  <text x="12" y="63" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="46" fill="#ffffff">AA</text>
</svg>
```